# How to make Windows 10 3D Builder automatically load .mtl material when opening OBJ 3d files with textures?

Tags: windows-10

When I open an `.obj` file in Windows it helpfully uses 3D Builder, and it also "understands" how to load texture files.

The way that wavefront obj 3d files work is that they use material files to define reference texture files.

This is a really simple case where at least three files correspond to one 3D asset. An obj 3d model file, a nearly trivial mtl file that references the texture, and the texture file which is a jpg.

All of these files are in the same folder.

When opening the obj, 3D Builder does not realize that the mtl is in the same folder. And it prompts, requiring us to "Proceed" to search the filesystem for the mtl and then subsequently all referenced image files.

THEY ARE ALL IN THE SAME FOLDER!

The flow is slightly better when using the 3D Builder's Open -> Load Object menu, this remembers the directory that you opened the .obj from, at least, but I have to manually navigate to the .obj file to begin with in the UI as well.

I wonder if there is any configuration that can help improve this horrible workflow. I guess maybe if the obj/mtl files used absolute paths to reference the file it may work the way I want it to.

Comment: it is understandably a bit of downvote bait. i dont think wavefront has been around for over 20 years. I am mostly just venting and microsoft bashing.

Comment: "I am mostly just venting and microsoft bashing." so remove it and you won't be downvoted

Answer (score 2):

Steven,

I'm an engineer on the 3D Builder team.

The pain you at experiencing is a UWP app limitation. All UWP apps are unable to access the file system directly. If a file is needed it must be selected by the user through the file explorer prompt. The app is unable to look in the same folder as the original obj file because it doesn't have permissions.

On the flip side, we could do better at remembering the folder where you opened the original file and opening up further prompts in that same location.

Thanks for letting us know!

Comment: Would it be fair to say that Steven should probably use the Feedback App on his Win10 computer and create a Feedback entry for recent folder improvement opportunity?

Comment: Hello everyone. I was being really rather entitled and belligerent in the question, my apologies, I was very frustrated with this because it was a solid piece of software, just fell short by a few steps. *Nevertheless*, the team from Microsoft has provided an answer here courteously. And look!!! In the Fall Creator's update, the 3D Builder opens up an OBJ tile with materials and multiple texture files exactly the way I wanted it to. It works out of the box now. THANK YOU for making this software work the way that it really should. It improves my workflow a lot!

Comment: What you could do is improve UWP to be able to load files from more places. Add more user permission. I don't actually understand this limitation. I load assets from the install folder in my UWP application without opening a file picker. It's one thing having application security, but if you can't do basic tasks like loading 3d models where you find them, then you've got a bit of a problem.

Comment: @Cory Given it has been 3 years, can we get an update? Is there *any* way to load the MTL file for a .OBJ file? Any way at all? Doesn't even have to be automatic, just need something.

Answer (score 0):

As music2myear points out, it would be helpful to leave this feedback in the Feedback Hub app on his Windows 10 machine under the "Apps and Games" -> "3D Builder" section. This will allow others to upvote the feedback and better get it on our radar.

Thanks, Steven and Music2!

Comment: This should have been submitted as a comment.  Comments should never be submitted as an answer.